# How to get TFPGList pointer to item?

Tags: freepascal

I have list which is `TFPGList<TmyRec>` and I need pointer to item's record `TMyRec` with index N. Not entire record `Items[N]` but pointer to item's record. How to get this pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant. the `.List` member that returned an array of pointer in the classic non-generic `TFPList` is replaced by a `array[0..MaxGListSize] of T`.

This means that if `T` is not a reference type (for example a class or a pointer to a record) then this array stores the full value for each item and not a pointer to the item, like in the old days.